# Part of title duplicating but not sure how to remove from code - help?

Tags: php, title, duplicates

I inherited a problem that no one in my office can figure out.

Our company website has page titles in the format of "Page Name Company Name - Company Name." The first instance of Company Name is a duplicate and needs to be deleted (it should be Page Name - Company Name), but I'm not sure how to proceed from looking at the code. This is a custom WP theme that is a child of the 2014 stock theme. Does anything in this title code snippet stand out?

```
<title>
       <?php
          if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
             single_tag_title("Tag Archive for &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
          elseif (is_archive()) {
             wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; }
          elseif (is_search()) {
             echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; }
          elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
             wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
          elseif (is_404()) {
             echo 'Not Found - '; }

          if (is_home()) {
             bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
          else {
              bloginfo('name'); }
          if ($paged>1) {
             echo ' - page '. $paged; }
       ?>
</title>
```

Comment: If you go to `Settings -> General` do you have `Company Name` in both the Site Title and Tagline field?

Comment: Nope, it's just in the site title field.

Comment: Do you have any SEO plugins installed such as Yoast that you could disable?

Comment: Nope! :) No SEO plugins on this site.

Comment: Do you have a fragment like this `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`

Answer (score 1):

You're on a page and if we read through the list of conditionals it should hit this one specifically:

```
elseif( ! ( is_404() ) && ( is_single() ) || ( is_page() ) ) {
    wp_title( '' );
    echo ' - ';
}
```

It will also hit the below conditional in the next set:

```
else {
    bloginfo( 'name' );
}
```

Given page `Test Page` we should see `Page Name - Company Name` but the parent Twenty Fourteen theme has this filter on `wp_title()`:

```
function twentyfourteen_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentyfourteen_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Notice that it is also appending the Website Name to the title ( directly after the feed conditional ) which is why we end up seeing the company name twice. You can comment out the above line to remove the duplication.

```
function twentyfourteen_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    // DONT Add the site name.
    // $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentyfourteen_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/29/title-tags-in-4-1/

```
function theme_slug_setup() {
   add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
```

> By declaring support like this, themes acknowledge that they are not defining titles on their own and WordPress can add it safely without duplication.